# neo4j OGM incorrect relationship population

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I use spring + neo4j ogm and have some troubles while querying entity.

```
class A {
    @Relationship(type="ABR")
    private List<B> bList;
}

interface ARepository extends GraphRepository<A> { ... }
```

I my neo4j db I have two types of relations between A and B entities: "ABR", "XYZ" and I interested in "ABR" connection. But when I call *repository.findAll()* it populates bList with all connected B entities (either via "ABR" and "XYZ").

Does anybody know how can I fix this issue?

PS: I can not remove totally "XYZ" connection because I need it in another logic.

This problem only occurs when I don't declare

`@Relationship(type="XYZ")
private List<B> xyzList;`

I use Spring Boot 1.5.11 and here are next versions of spring data and neo4j ogm: spring-data-neo4j-4.2.11, neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.6

Comment: Which is nothing **at all** to do with the JPA API or even the Spring Data JPA API. That is spring data neo4j ... totally different API

Comment: Since you are using the old `GraphRepository` it would help to know which versions of Spring Data Neo4j and Neo4j-OGM you are using.